# Define next_step programmatically in the JSON editor in IBM Watson conversation

Tags: json, watson-conversation

I want to direct the user to a specific node if a context variable is not defined yet. The next step should do that but I cannot define it programmatically in a multiple responses scenario.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time all responses in a single node have to follow the same next step, ie a single response cannot jump somewhere while the others do not.

A simple workaround would be to just utilize two dialog nodes one after the other, and if the first one evaluates to true then it will continue that way, if not, it will evaluate the second node, and follow that way which would be your separate jump to.

We do have this feautre on our backlog to allow jump tos from individual conditional responses, so we will implement it eventually, but no timing is set at this time.